# Tensorflow Increase Test Accuracy

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, keras, tensorflow2.0

Guys I am new to tensorflow, just there have been 2 days since I have started to learn. I follow and make the steps of tensorflow and note the meaning of codes. After that I try to do similar project just like I have done in tensorflow tutorials.

Due to just there have been 2 days, I have tried to make a image classification. But accuracy of test results are so bad and it doesnt make true evaluation.

Can you please guide, teach me how can I improve this code or what should I learn to improve this code...

**Notes:**
-I have made the project in colabs.google(You can try it here by copying the code)
-The dataset that I have taken ===> [https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Ekriz/cifar.html)

This is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow import keras

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

(train_i, train_l), (test_i, test_l) = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()

classnames = ['airplane', 'automobile', 'bird', 'cat', 'deer', 'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck']

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

model = keras.Sequential([    
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'), #burada kaç tane node olacağını belirtiyoruz yani mesela burada 108 se 108 tane node vardır. Node sayısını arrtırdıkça işlem hızımız düşüyor ama tahmin değerlerimiz gerçeğe daha yakın oluyor.
    keras.layers.Dense(10) #burada ise 10 diyoruz çünkü 10 tane class içinden seçecek.
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_i, train_l, epochs=100)

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_i,  test_l, verbose=2)
print(test_acc)
prediction = tf.keras.Sequential([model, tf.keras.layers.Softmax()]).predict(test_i)

i = 90

prediction[i]

prediction_made= np.argmax(prediction[i])

f= train_l[i]

s=str(train_l[i])
print(str(s)[1:-1])

b = int(str(s)[1:-1])

y = classnames[b]

x = classnames[prediction_made]

img = train_i
plt.grid(False)
plt.xticks([]) 
plt.yticks([]) 
plt.imshow(img[i])

plt.xlabel('The True Label is ' + repr(y) + 
           ', and The Predicted Label is ' + repr(x) + '...')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 'model' is justified twice.

1. models.Sequential() ...
2. model = keras.Sequential(...)

so first part doesn't included in final 'model'.

Modify model part code like this

```
model = keras.Sequential([  
   keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32 ,3)),
   keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),                     
   keras.layers.Flatten(),
   keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'),
   keras.layers.Dense(10)
])
```

Comment: I tried it but it says: line 36
    ])
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Ö.ALPERENGÜL
I don't know what your 36th line is.
Check this colab page I made. It works: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1LRAeKAr2i4DZ8MzfN9LHXevTjpidQY9-?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks and can I ask another else?  Why that the accuracy is so low? How can I improve it?

Comment: @Ö.ALPERENGÜL which accuracy do you mean? 

`Epoch 100/100
1563/1563 [==============================] - 36s 23ms/step - loss: 0.4011 - accuracy: 0.8601`

At epoch 100, model's accuracy is 86% and this is not that low.